# Specialization of variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to aggregate the value of member variables for some arbitrary number of a specific type hierarchy that I have defined.

This is fine and easy to do using a variadic templated function.

Where I am not having much luck is when I try to pass in the name of the function that is calling this template as a string as the first argument.
This is rather hard to explain so below is some code that I have to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

Trying to compile this results in:
error C2993: 'std::string' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'str'

Is what I am attempting to do impossible? Or am I just going about it this in the wrong way?

```
std::ostringstream output;
int objCounter = 0;

void set_results() {
    output << "\n" << std::endl;
}

template <typename obj,  typename ...objs>
void set_results(obj objHead, objs... objTail) {
    ++objCounter;
    output << "Argument (" << objCounter << ") \t" << objHead.bytes << std::endl;
    set_results(objTail...);
}

template <std::string str, typename ...objs>
void set_results(std::string objHead, objs... objTail) {
    output << "Leaf Function: " << objHead << std::endl;
    set_results(objTail...);
}

class objDep {
public:
    int bytes;
    objDep(int b) : bytes(b) {}
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    objDep one(1);
    objDep two(2);
    objDep three(3);
    objDep four(4);

    set_results(std::string("main"), one, two, three, four);

    std::cout << output.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need `std::string str` in the template parameter list at all:

```
template <typename ...objs>
void set_results(std::string objHead, objs... objTail)
```

It’s unused, first of all, and non-type template parameters can only be integers (`int`, `long`, etc.), enumerations, or function symbols.

A template specifies the manner in which a function or class is generic. Saying:

```
template <typename obj, typename ...objs>
void set_results(obj objHead, objs... objTail)
```

Means “given some type, call it `obj`, and some list of types, call them `objs`, `set_results` takes a value of type `obj` and a series of values respectively of type `objs`, and returns `void`”.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
template <std::string str, typename ...objs>
void set_results(std::string objHead, objs... objTail) {
    output << "Leaf Function: " << objHead << std::endl;
    set_results(objTail...);
}
```

to:

```
template <typename ...objs>
void set_results(std::string objHead, objs... objTail) {
    output << "Leaf Function: " << objHead << std::endl;
    set_results(objTail...);
}
```

You can't have a template parameter of type `std::string`, and at any rate it's entirely unclear what you intended for `str` to represent anyway.

Note that function templates cannot be partially specialized. With this replacement, you'll have two *overloads* of `set_results`. The one with the `std::string` parameter will be selected because it's more specialized.